# Multiple HTML files linked to only one Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have functions in an external Javascript file to be linked to each of my html files. However, I want some functions to be linked to one html file while other functions would be linked to a different html file. Do I need to have multiple Javascript files or can I condense them into only one file? When I tried to use one Javascript file every function would run on each of my pages. Is there a way to call a specific function in html without having the whole code? Like with css using `#example` for the id `example` in html.

I used this link in my index.html file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>`

While this one was in another html file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="example2.js"></script>`

These links are the only Javascript included in my html files.

---

I think I found the problem. I have an RSS feed that comes through a free website but the function doesn't have anything next to it.

The html file links to the Javascript file with this in it and because the function is blank it automatically runs or that's what i'm assuming.

```
(function(){
var a=window;
var b="";
for(i=0;i<a.rssfeed_url.length;i++) {
    b=b+"rssfeed[url]["+i+"]="+encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_url[i])+"&"
}
var c="http://feed.surfing-waves.com/php/rssfeed.php"+"?"+b+"rssfeed[type]="+(a.rssfeed_type?a.rssfeed_type:"")+"&rssfeed[frame_width]="+a.rssfeed_frame_width+"&rssfeed[frame_height]="+a.rssfeed_frame_height+"&rssfeed[scroll]="+(a.rssfeed_scroll?a.rssfeed_scroll:"")+"&rssfeed[scroll_step]="+(a.rssfeed_scroll_step?a.rssfeed_scroll_step:"")+"&rssfeed[scroll_bar]="+(a.rssfeed_scroll_bar?a.rssfeed_scroll_bar:"")+"&rssfeed[target]="+(a.rssfeed_target?a.rssfeed_target:"")+"&rssfeed[font_size]="+(a.rssfeed_font_size?a.rssfeed_font_size:"")+"&rssfeed[font_face]="+(a.rssfeed_font_face?a.rssfeed_font_face:"")+"&rssfeed[border]="+(a.rssfeed_border?a.rssfeed_border:"")+"&rssfeed[css_url]="+(a.rssfeed_css_url?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_css_url):"")+"&rssfeed[title]="+(a.rssfeed_title?a.rssfeed_title:"")+"&rssfeed[title_name]="+(a.rssfeed_title_name?a.rssfeed_title_name:"")+"&rssfeed[title_bgcolor]="+(a.rssfeed_title_bgcolor?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_title_bgcolor):"")+"&rssfeed[title_color]="+(a.rssfeed_title_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_title_color):"")+"&rssfeed[title_bgimage]="+(a.rssfeed_title_bgimage?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_title_bgimage):"")+"&rssfeed[footer]="+(a.rssfeed_footer?a.rssfeed_footer:"")+"&rssfeed[footer_name]="+(a.rssfeed_footer_name?a.rssfeed_footer_name:"")+"&rssfeed[footer_bgcolor]="+(a.rssfeed_footer_bgcolor?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_footer_bgcolor):"")+"&rssfeed[footer_color]="+(a.rssfeed_footer_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_footer_color):"")+"&rssfeed[footer_bgimage]="+(a.rssfeed_footer_bgimage?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_footer_bgimage):"")+"&rssfeed[item_bgcolor]="+(a.rssfeed_item_bgcolor?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_bgcolor):"")+"&rssfeed[item_bgimage]="+(a.rssfeed_item_bgimage?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_bgimage):"")+"&rssfeed[item_title_length]="+(a.rssfeed_item_title_length?a.rssfeed_item_title_length:"")+"&rssfeed[item_title_color]="+(a.rssfeed_item_title_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_title_color):"")+"&rssfeed[item_border_bottom]="+(a.rssfeed_item_border_bottom?a.rssfeed_item_border_bottom:"")+"&rssfeed[item_source_icon]="+(a.rssfeed_item_source_icon?a.rssfeed_item_source_icon:"")+"&rssfeed[item_date]="+(a.rssfeed_item_date?a.rssfeed_item_date:"")+"&rssfeed[item_description]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description?a.rssfeed_item_description:"")+"&rssfeed[item_description_length]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description_length?a.rssfeed_item_description_length:"")+"&rssfeed[item_description_color]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_description_color):"")+"&rssfeed[item_description_link_color]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description_link_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_description_link_color):"")+"&rssfeed[item_description_tag]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description_tag?a.rssfeed_item_description_tag:"")+"&rssfeed[no_items]="+(a.rssfeed_no_items?a.rssfeed_no_items:"")+"&rssfeed[cache]="+(a.rssfeed_cache?a.rssfeed_cache:"");
if(a.rssfeed_border!="off"&&!a.rssfeed_css_url){}
document.write('<iframe name="rssfeed_frame" width="'+a.rssfeed_frame_width+'" height="'+a.rssfeed_frame_height+'" frameborder="0" src="'+c+'" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" scrolling="no" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"></iframe>')
})()
```

The only problem now is that I don't know how to call the function. Another function I have is called because I have `onClick="example()"` which is fine for that but the RSS feed needs to load automatically. I don't want to have to click a button to get the feed to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions only run if you call them. So you can have one JS file that contains functions that are never called by one HTML file, and nothing goes wrong -- they have no impact on the functioning of the page. The only downside of extra unused code is that is takes longer to load, but that isn't really significant until the file gets very big.

Comment: Do you mind telling me how to call them? I got the Javascript code from a website and don't really know how it works. Without calling individual functions all of them continue to run on all of my pages.

Comment: If they are running, then there is code that is calling them. Does the javascript file have any code that is not within `function() {...}`? are there any functions that are surrounded by parentheses: `(function() {...})`?

Comment: When your javascript files are loaded by the browser, all the code in them is run. That's just what happens when you link a javascript file from an html file. To get around this, you can put some of the code in the files into "functions". A function is a bit of code that isn't run immediately when it's read by the browser. You can then go and use the functions you want to use somewhere else in that html page. To learn how to write and use funtions, I'd suggest looking at a basic book on javascript like this one: http://www.eloquentjavascript.net

Comment: The function is running because it is surrounded by parenthesis: that is the Javascript notation to immediately run the function being defined. If you want to run it automatically only from one page and not the other, remove the parens, and give it a name: `function loadRSS() {...}`, then call it from your HTML form: `<body onload="loadRSS()">`

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I just have one small problem. I want it within a div not just the body. If I try `<div id="newsfeed" onload="loadRSS">` it doesn't work. What do I use instead of body?

Comment: Code doesn't run within HTML elements - the `<body>` tag just gives a convenient place to call a function when the page loads. If you are trying to place the feed contents within a `<div>`, then change the line `document.write('<iframe...` to be `document.getElementById('newsfeed').innerHTML=<iframe...`

Comment: I can't get it to work so i'll just settle with having multiple Javascript files. You did help and teach me a lot though so thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a file named "common.js" that holds all related JavaScript functionality. But you will need separate JavaScript (either in a separate file or embedded in the HTML page itself) to make specific use of the common functionality according to the needs of the different pages.

After seeing some code, one may be able to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's more logical to split your javascript code into multiple files where it is appropriate. But you don't have to run any code in your javascript file even if it is linked to your html page if you put your code into functions.

```
function myFunction()
{
    // do something.
}
```

The code inside this function won't run unless you call it in your html.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
  ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that for example by adding id or class to the html or body, and then, write conditions, if the element (html or body) contains the id/class execute the appropriate functions.
When are the functions called? On page load?
If you provide sample code, it would be better.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski im aware of that, its just in the question it is not clear when are the functions called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use location.pathname and check the path and use switch or if else